How to expand * into columns with given query and table with column list
I'm writing a code to expand a SELECT query that uses * or alias.* into SELECT query with defined column names.
The idea is to supply the query, table list and associated column list and return a query with all those columns defined within the query.
Example
table_names = ["my_table", "other_table"]
column_names = {
    "my_table": ["id", "column1", "column2"],
    "other_table": ["id", "column3", "column4"]
}
sql_query = """SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM my_table as m join other_table as o on o.id=m.id) AS subquery"""

result_query = """SELECT subquery.id,subquery.column1,subquery.column2,subquery.id,subquery.column3,subquery.column4 FROM (SELECT my_table.id,my_table.column1,my_table.column2,other_table.id,other_table.column3,other_table.column4 FROM my_table as m join other_table as o on o.id=m.id) AS subquery

I have tried getting the column list vie sql_metadata, but I was wondering if there's a library that can already do it.
If not, do we just get a list of tables and append the column list side by side?
Thanks in advance.
NOTE: I cannot directly connect to the DB and need to do this outside of the system with python

What do you mean you can't connect to the DB? How else would you get the column names? Do you know them beforehand? Are you just trying to replace the * like a wild card from your pre-defined column_names dictionary? It's not clear.

Yes exactly. I can query the DB via API call, but not with a direct connection.
I can make Select queries to get the column names for a given table from INFORMATION_SCHEMA
And yes, I'm just trying to replace the * or alias.* with the full column names

If you do have the option to query information_schema.columns, I'm not sure what the problem is then. If a client library knows and is able to expand/suggest the column names, that or pg_attribute is exactly how it gets that information. You can also add a limit 0 to the query and the db will do that same expansion for you, assembling an empty result structure with column names and types.

Would that be affected by structure of the query? If there are bunch of nested queries within it, will it take a long time, or is the engine smart enough to only query one row to get the data.
I want to avoid taxing the system as the tables used are quite large.
